# Consulta SQL con valores parecidos

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo que hacer una consulta a una base de usando como comparación un string como este `12345678`, pero el valor a comparar esta de esta forma `12.345.678`, si hago la siguiente consulta no me regresa nada

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE CAMPO = '12345678'
```

Donde CAMPO tendria el valor de (12.345.678), si reemplazo el `=` por un `like` tampoco me retorna los datos

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE CAMPO like '12345678%'
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE CAMPO like '%12345678'
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE CAMPO like '%12345678%'
```

Ninguna de las 3 consultas anteriores me funciona, ¿como puedo hacer esta consulta?

Comment: qué versión de MySQL usas? mayor o menor a 5.5?

Comment: @PakLei Mayor a 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En MySQL >= 5.5 puedes usar la función **format** para representar de distintas maneras una columna:

```
SELECT FORMAT(12345678, 0, 'de_DE') AS format;
```

Te devolvería el siguiente string: **12.345.678**

Puedes agregar lo anterior en el **where** de tu select para resolverlo.

```
SELECT * from tabla where campo = FORMAT("12345678",0,'de_DE');
```

Comment: Diculpa hermano, y para sql-server como seria?, por que no me funciona hay

Comment: Existe la función **STR** en SQL SERVER que puede utilizarse para lograr algo igual o similar...